# Sql Server Stored procedure returns -1

Tags: sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, parameters, output

I am writing code on entity framework 6.0, linq on asp.net, sql server platform.

I've written a stored procedure which supposed to return an output value (0 or 1)

Firstly I wrote SP by using output parameter as follows:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[checkUser]
(
    @oNo int,
    @pw varchar(50),
    @val int output
)
as
begin
    if EXISTS (select * from Users where @oNo=sNo and @pw=password)
        begin
        set @val=1
        end
    if not exists(select * from Users where @oNo=sNo and @pw=password)
        begin
        set @val=0
        end

end
```

Didnt work. It returned -1. Then I changed SP like this:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[checkUser]
(
    @oNo int,
    @pw varchar(50)
)
as
begin
    if EXISTS (select * from Users where @oNo=sNo and @pw=password)
        begin
        return 1
        end
    else
        begin
        return 0
        end

end
```

Each ways stored procedure returns only -1

Can you help me please, where am i doing wrong?

Comment: ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("val", typeof(int));
                var d = context.checkUser(Convert.ToInt32(txtONo.Text), txtPw.Text, output);

                var d=context.checkUser(Convert.ToInt32(txtONo.Text),txtPw.Text);
                if (d==1)
                {
                    //
                }
                else if(d==0)
                {
                    //
                }

Comment: you are using function import?

Comment: Well, I mapped database to entity framework. So the stored procedure which i wrote in sql side, exists in function import as the same name as in the sql side; called 'checkUser'.

Comment: Sorry the code was like this: ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("val", typeof(int)); var d = context.checkUser(Convert.ToInt32(txtONo.Text), txtPw.Text, output); if (d==1) { // } else if(d==0) { // }

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "return" by "select".

```
if EXISTS (select * from Users where @oNo=sNo and @pw=password)
    begin
    select 1
    end
else
    begin
    select 0
    end
```

Comment: Just tried. Its weird this way it returns only "0". Altough I tried both true and wrong parameter matches for sp..